# Custom keyboard in TelegramBot using MS Bot Framework

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, botframework

As far as i know, i can youse Actions (http://blog.botframework.com/2016/05/13/BotFramework.buttons/) to create inline keyboards in Telegram and other messages. 
But what about Custom Keyboards (https://core.telegram.org/bots#keyboards)? How can i add them using Bot Framework?

I read about ChannelData (http://docs.botframework.com/connector/custom-channeldata/#custom-telegram-messages), but i didnt get, how can i pass JSON to CreateReplyMessage method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CreateReplyMessage to create a Message object:

```
var replyMessage =  incomingMessage.CreateReplyMessage("Yo, I heard you.");
```

Then set the ChannelData

```
replyMessage.ChannelData = {custom Telegram JSON}
```

Comment: @DenisovJr. hi, do you have sample code to send `keyboard`?

Comment: See the Telegram Keyboard docs:  https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton

Answer (score 1):

For Bot Framework v4:

```
{
    var reply = context.Context.Activity.CreateReply(messageText);

    if (BotDialogHelpers.ExtractMessengerFromDialogContext(context) == BotDialogHelpers.Messengers.Telegram)
    {
        GenerateReplyMarkupForTelegram(reply);
    }

    await context.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply, token);
}

/// <summary>
/// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-channeldata?view=azure-bot-service-3.0
/// https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message sendMessage reply_markup
/// </summary>
private void GenerateReplyMarkupForTelegram(IActivity reply)
{
    var replyMarkup = new
    {
        reply_markup = new
        {
            remove_keyboard = true,
        }
    };

    var channelData = new
    {
        method = "sendMessage",
        parameters = replyMarkup,
    };

    reply.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(channelData);
}
```